How can I recognise undeclared primitives with Jackson?
I have the following Jackson class:
public class InspectArrayFormulaArgs {

    private final int expectedColumns;

    @JsonCreator
    public InspectArrayFormulaArgs(@JsonProperty(value = "expectedColumns", defaultValue = "-1") int expectedColumns) {
        this.expectedColumns = expectedColumns;
    }

}

I would expect Jackson to check whether the parsed Json contains the field expectedColumns, and:

If the field is there, take it as is
Else, use the defaultValue that I declared

However, the value parsed by Jackson is still 0 when this pojo is parsed.
I've thought it may be due to the fact that the JDK initialises an int as 0 and Jackson doesn't understand the field is not in the Json (even though I thought they were parsing the Json directly).
So I've tried to use Integer instead of int as a parameter for the constructor, but this ends up into a NullPointerException because Jackson doesn't assign the value -1 and so the JDK tries an unboxing of null into the field int expectedColumns.
Any idea on how I should do this?
Notes:

I've tried annotating the class with @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_DEFAULT) but it didn't change anything
I assume I may declare the field as being an Integer instead of int, but Jackson still leaves it as null (doesn't assign -1) and I wanted to avoid doing checks on my side such as value != null ? value : -1. Of course I'll do that if no solution, but I find it strange that Jackson is uncapable to understand what I'm asking so I'm wondering whether it's me asking it the wrong way


The defaultValue element is for documentation purposes only. It has no practical effect.

Property that may be used to document expected default value for the property: most often used as source information for generating schemas (like JSON Schema or protobuf/thrift schema), or documentation. It may also be used by Jackson extension modules; core jackson-databind does not have any automated handling beyond simply exposing this value through bean property introspection.

You could provide a different default value by overriding getNullValue in a custom deserialiser.
@JsonCreator
public InspectArrayFormulaArgs(
        @JsonDeserialize(using = DefaultMinusOneDeserializer.class)
        @JsonProperty(value = "expectedColumns", defaultValue = "-1")
        int expectedColumns
) {
    this.expectedColumns = expectedColumns;
}

static class DefaultMinusOneDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Integer> {
    @Override
    public Integer deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException {
        return jsonParser.getIntValue();
    }

    @Override
    public Integer getNullValue(DeserializationContext ctxt) {
        return -1;
    }
}

